# composer doesn't install dotenv on Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have Symfony 3.4 project and am trying to install the Dotenv component.
I've ran this command `composer require symfony/dotenv:^3.4` and composer said "Nothing to install or update".

I've deleted `vendor` folder also tried to install the Dotenv component on brand new Symfony 3.4 project, the result is the same.
Any ideas?

Comment: do a `composer show symfony/dotenv`

Comment: `[InvalidArgumentException] Package symfony/dotenv not found`

Comment: What makes you think that this package is not yet installed? Can you share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing `symfony/symfony` (~3.4) the `symfony/dotenv` is already installed.

Take a look at [Packagist symfony/symfony#v3.4.43](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony#v3.4.43). As you can see, it "replaces" the package called `symfony/dotenv`, which is expected.

Instead of using `composer show`, try asking `composer why symfony/dotenv`. It clearly states: `symfony/symfony replaces symfony/dotenv`.

Also take a look at your lokal *vendor/* directory. There you should find the source you're looking for:

```
ls -l vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Dotenv/
```